# Template editor malfunction after update to 2.9.0

Tags: ee2, ee2-upgrades, editor

Yesterday I updated one of my site to 2.9.0 (from 2.5.x ... yes I know ...) anyhow everything worked well except that the template editor is not working as before. Meaning:

- I can't insert tab spaces anymore as then the editor move my cursor to the next field (Preference, Template name)
- The Preferences, Access and Template notes block are always visible and I cannot collapse them anymore....

I'm just rebuilding the site of my customer and editing thousands of lines like this will not be easy ;-)

As anyone seen this before? thanks in advance for any hint.

Steven

Comment: I have yet to install the release of 2.9 but the developer preview had a new template editor in place that color-coded text and added line numbers. While nice and all, it broke the "TabinTA" add-on that I often use in FireFox to bridge the gap between the CP template editor and a stand-alone text editor. I requested a hidden config override be added so that the new editor could be turned off...EL said it wouldn't be a problem but I don't see it in the list:http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/general/system_configuration_overrides.html Are you seeing line numbers in the code editor?

Comment: I've just upgraded from 2.8 - 2.9 and the Editor is working fine. By default I see line numbers and color-coded text, and tabbing works nicely. There is also a button on far top right, that toggles between this editor and alternative with no tabbing or colors option. If your preference toggles are not working either, may I suggest a javascript issue, perhaps something isn't loading.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually no, I do not see line numbers, the background turns yellow when I click to edit anything but that's it. On top the Save and submit button does not quick the edit as before, it just save (not always) but remains in the template edit view ... Seems to me all broken or something went wrong with the update? Steven

Comment: @MichaelBoyink we incorporated a disabler without having a hidden config via the "Toggle Editor" button in the upper right hand side of the template editor page.

Comment: Well, unfortunately the Toggle Editor button ha son function on my site, like the rest of the Template Editor it is malfunctioning

Comment: Hi Just to say that I have updated to 2.9 from 2.7.2 and I getting the exact same issue. The template editor shows just a load of numbers displayed vertically like they are row numbers. When click save template as file I get the same message 'Unable to save your template as a text file'...

Comment: Ok correction there, Click the toggle editor button and you can then see the template code and edit it. I then realised the path to the theme folder was wrong. All working well now :)

Answer (score 2):

This was an odd one!  It turns out it was a suhosin.get.max_value_length setting.

Any value over 128 characters, the variable was dropped from $_GET.  And our combo loader specifies the files to pull in to create the js file via $_GET:

```
plugin=ee_codemirror&amp;file=codemirror/codemirror,codemirror/closebrackets,codemirror/lint,codemirror/overlay,etc, etc, way more than 128 etc....
```

When the comboloader created the js file, there was no file value since it had been dropped entirely- and none of that code was being included in the resulting js file.  Hence massive breakage.

Tweaking the server config gets it squared away.

Answer (score 1):

When working on larger projects, i usually write templates to files. That way you can more easily edit in a "real" editor (like sublime etc.) and store a copy in an archive or even version control with git or mercurial.

After everything works, you only have to sync all templates via the template manager once (and optionally disable templates as files to serve from database)

If you think there's a malfunction with template editor, maybe file a bug report.

Comment: Hi, well if I would have knew that before I would have done that. But now the "Save as a file" is also not working anymore and just throwing error messages "Unable to save your template as a text file"

Answer (score 1):

Did you remember to [update your themes](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/installation/update.html#upload-new-files)? There is new JavaScript in 2.9.0 that handles the improved template editor. If you open your console on that page, I'm going to guess you have a number of JS errors (which also explains why your fields at the bottom are toggled open).

Comment: Thanks for your message :-) Yes, I did it, and did it again (to be sure) few minutes ago, but still same issue.

Comment: Forgot to answer a part. the console does not show any javascript error, nor other errors ... it was my first look ... it is really strange.

Comment: Update. Re-did a totally fresh install following strictly the instruction in the new manual (not using the Haddon Updater) and still the same, expect one thing ... now I see something in the console:                                         [Error] ReferenceError: Can't find variable: CodeMirror
 o (index.php, line 12)
 (anonymous function) (index.php, line 12)
 each (jquery.js, line 16)
 each (jquery.js, line 16)
 toggleCodeMirror (index.php, line 12)
 global code (index.php, line 1)

Comment: Sounds like you are missing some JavaScript still, @Steven. Verify that in your theme folder on the remote server that you actually have `/themes/javascript/compressed/codemirror/*` and then try clearing your browser caches and refreshing.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Well I looked for the core mirror files. This folder exists. Cache is clean, and this I tried on several browsers (Safari, Chrome, Firefox).  I should also mentioned that the php version on the Debian 6 server was not the most actual one, so I updated it manually ... in case of. But still no luck unfortunately. Maybe another idea or check I could make? Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Try accessing the JS files directly via the browser. Maybe it's a permissions issue.

Comment: I installed a MAMP on my dev Mac with a fresh install install of EE 2.9 and the editor is working good. I also used the same php version I have on my main server. I believe this has to do something with something on my server. Do you have a more precise list of requirements from EE2.9 as the one posted into the documentation?

Comment: I just did the test, in the resources called I see 4 css (code mirror-addition.css, code mirror.css, global.css & query-ui-1.8.16.custom.css) and only one js file (jquery.js) which I can access without any issue from the browser. Should not it loads also some js files from code mirror?

Comment: All of the other JS on the page is called via a combo loader. Did you try accessing the JS files directly as I suggested above? e.g. `http://example.com/themes/javascript/compressed/codemiddor/codemirror.js`.  If you cannot access them, neither can PHP, so the combo JS loader in the ExpressionEngine control panel would fail.

Comment: Yes, I can access it in the web browser and see the source of the file, so no issue on access. I have mod-security on the apache2, I also looked there to see if anything was blocked, but nothing apparent showing up.

Comment: And what happens if you load the combo-loaded resource URL directly? `http://example.com/admin.php?S=0&D=cp&C=javascript&M=combo_load&plugin=ee_codemirror&file=codemirror/codemirror,codemirror/closebrackets,codemirror/lint,codemirror/overlay,codemirror/xml,codemirror/css,codemirror/javascript,codemirror/htmlmixed,codemirror/ee-mode,codemirror/dialog,codemirror/searchcursor,codemirror/search,cp/template_editor,cp/manager`

Comment: It gives me a blank page (I authenticated before into another tab to the admin interface), and when I say a blank page, really blank, looking at the source there is nothing coming from the server, but the "page" loads and the browser finished loading ... nothing ;-) No error

Comment: Trying the error console in Firefox, when clicking on the Editor toggle button I get the following error (in the console):  Could not load the source for javascript:$('#template_data').toggleCodeMirror();.
[Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE) [nsIChannel.asyncOpen]"  nsresult: "0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE)"  location: "JS frame :: resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/devtools/server/main.js -> resource://gre/modules/devtools/server/actors/script.js :: fetch :: line 5218"  data: no]Line: 5218, column: 0

Comment: Yes, you will get JS errors because those files are not being loaded. ;) In your admin.php file, set `$debug = 1;` and try loading it with the combo loader URL again.

Comment: I just did it and the page is also empty. No new error message. Thanks in advance if you have more idea what to check.

Comment: Something in your environment or files is preventing it from working. But since it's a local MAMP environment, no one else can debug it but you without network sharing your machine (or someone else sitting at your machine). I would check your error logs—there is undoubtedly something being logged that will pinpoint the problem when you request that URL even though MAMP may be hiding it from your browser.

Comment: Hi, actually it is a normal debian 6 server in a data centre, MAMP was only a test I made to check if I saw the same behaviour (no). This instance of EE is actually used for production and the machine is accessible. Should I pay and request a support officially? After reading all I could about code mirror, expression engine with javascript issue, I think I cannot solve it alone. Do you think it would be possible for someone to check it without getting root access to the server (I have other websites with confidential data...). Maybe you work for ellislab so you can advise me what to do?

Comment: Yes our engineers can log in via SFTP and take a look for you with a support ticket. It will not cost if you are a license holder and have not redeemed your three months of free support already.

Comment: Well I have already 3 licenses, my last one is recent but I never redeemed any ticket. the issue is that when I go to support I cannot create any ticket, it says I must plan a support plan. Or is there any link/area I did not see?

Comment: That message should be a link to the [store](https://store.ellislab.com/) where you can sign up for Support. If you haven't redeemed any yet, Silver will be free (and reflect in your cart).

Comment: Oh yes you are right, I just did it. So I'll submit a ticket, with maybe a reference to our thread, while already some basic checks were made.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your tips and help. Really appreciate :-)